# TYPO3 Lazy Loading Error

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

I get the error

> Argument 1 passed to
>   [...]\FrontendUserRepository::findMasterByVkbur()
>   must be an instance of [...]\MyModel,
>   instance of TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\LazyLoadingProxy
>   given, called in [...]\MyController.php on line 123

Why is the argument still a "LazyLoadingProxy" and not a "MyModel"?

This is line 123 in MyController.php:

```
$frontendUsers = $this->frontendUserRepository->findMasterByVkbur($this->feuser->getVkbur());
```

This is the "vkbur" object:

```
/**
 * @var \MyVendor\MyExt\Domain\Model\MyModel
 * @lazy
 */
protected $vkbur = null;
```

When "using" the object before, e.g. with...

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\DebugUtility::debug($this->feuser->getVkbur());
```

...I do not get this error in line 123.

Comment: I found a workaround by using function "_loadRealInstance" in the getter function "getVkbur", but Extbase should do this automatically, shouldn't it?

Comment: Extbase does not do this automatically, Fluid does. You can access properties of lazy loaded objects in your Template, and Fluid will tkae care of resolving the objects. But if you want to access them in your ControllerAction you'll have to _loadRealInstance first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution seems to be to check the type of the variable in the getter method:

```
/**
 * @return \MyVendor\MyExt\Domain\Model\MyModel $vkbur
 */
public function getVkbur() {
    if($this->vkbur instanceof \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\LazyLoadingProxy) {
        $this->vkbur->_loadRealInstance();
    }
    return $this->vkbur;
}
```

Comment: Weird. Just as I was posting a small edit to the answer @rené-pflamm posted, I was thinking the same. Why isn't this part of the domain model getters, in fact, why isn't this just built into the getters by the extension builder?

Comment: This might be by far the most helpful answer I have found so far on SO. This will help me so so much in so many projects. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As described [here](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/60460) and [here](https://wiki.typo3.org/Enhanced_Lazy_Loading)

This was an topic, but was abandoned.

The Solution seems to be what you comment says:

```
if ($this->feuser->getVkbur() instanceof \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\LazyLoadingProxy) {
 $vkbur = $this->feuser->getVkbur()->_loadRealInstance();
} else {
 $vkbur = $this->feuser->getVkbur();
}
$frontendUsers = $this->frontendUserRepository->findMasterByVkbur(vkbur);
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking for LazyLoadingProxy as shown above still seems to be required in some cases. But shouldn't that be solved like explained here? https://wiki.typo3.org/Enhanced_Lazy_Loading